# in apache config, how should I use the Alias module for a directory in the document root?

Tags: apache, alias, document-root

### Background

Using Ubuntu with apache2:

In my `sites-enabled` config I have an `Alias` command like so:

```
Alias "/someDir" "/webSiteDir"
```

It works great.

So, the absolute path of `/someDir` is actually a "virtual directory" which effectively exists at `/var/www/html/someDir`.  Whereas `/webSiteDir` actually exists at the root of the Ubuntu box's file system.

### Question 1

How would I créate an Alias from one directory *in the document root* to another directory *also in the document root*?  The manual for Apache specifically says that `Alias` should be used for redirecting to directories *outside the document root*.  So what should I use if both the "virtual directory" and the actual directory are *inside the document root*?

Right now, I have it working with the following line:

```
Alias "/anotherDir" "/var/www/html/thisDir"
```

That seems quite clunky when the document root is explicitly defined just a few lines up as `var/www/html` within the very same config.

Should I be using a different command other than `Alias` for when both directories are under the same document root?

### Question 2

How does the apache config even correctly determine the absolute path of different entries?

For example, in the above line:
    Alias "/anotherDir" "/var/www/html/thisDir"
`/anotherDir` is treated as a "virtual directory" under `/var/www/html/` but the second part which is `/var/www/html/thisDir` is treated as an absolute path with regards to the Ubuntu file system.

Ok fine, maybe that is just the syntax of the `Alias` command, in that the first entry is always relative and the second entry is always absolute.

Well what about the `<Directory>` attribute?

I have one entry:
    `<Directory "/">`
which seems to refer to the document root of `/var/www/html/` - a relative path.

And I also have:
    `<Directory "/thisDir">`
which seems to refer to `/var/www/html/thisDir` - another relative path

Whereas I have another:
    `<Directory "/webSiteDir">`
which seems to refer to an *absolute path* in the file system of `/webSiteDir`.

So, is my config file just messed up, or does apache somehow know when something is a relative path to the document root, or an absolute path from the system root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias does not care much about your documentroot in a sense. That is, just define Alias inside your VirtualHost, first argument is a new virtual path and second is always a filesystem path, can be or it can not be inside the documentroot, Alias does not care or differentiate about it.

So, to question 1.

Always use alias to define virtualpaths, irrespectively where the filesystem is, just use it when you need it.

To question 2.

You have a BIG misunderstanding, Directory ALWAYS specifies a full path in your OS, that is `<Directory "/">`is  / in your OS Filesystem and the same with the rest of your "Directory" examples.

If you wanted to affect a path created with Alias, you would use "Location" or Directory with the full path, and that one is really relative to documentroot.

Comment: **Question 1**: So there is nothing wrong with using alias to define a relationship between two paths both inside the document root, even though the apache documentation (incorrectly?) states that it is for creating aliases to folders *outside* the document root?  **Question 2**: Thank you.  That was my misunderstanding then.

Comment: I don't think it is incorrect, but if you think they should correct it, go ahead and comment in the doc page or file a bug, I think they just state the obvious, Alias allows you to use a path you would never be able to when it is outside documentroot, generally it would not make much sense because you can just create that directory in documentroot and be done with it.

Comment: why would I create a directory in the document root if it is just going to be an alias for another directory?  I'm not trying to be combative: I'm asking if that is a better way to accomplish the same effect?

Comment: @Daniel yes, don't worry, we are just commenting not fighting. As I mentioned, generally you just create a directory, if by any chance you need an Alias, even if its inside documentroot path, by all means, use it.